# Give parent class if there is no child elements with classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of elements and I want to give a class to the parent tr element if the child inside it doesn't have a class assigned to it. Is this possible with jQuery or vanilla JS?

```
<tr>
 <td class="unfoldedlabel" colspan="6"><a>Accessories</a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td class="foldedlabel" colspan="6"><a>Accessories</a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td><a>Accessories</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: which class assign to parent and which class to child?

Comment: `$('tr:has(>:not(td[class]))').addClass('class')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)** and **[`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)**

```js
$('tr:has(>:not(td[class]))').addClass('class')
```

```css
.class {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="unfoldedlabel" colspan="6"><a>Accessories</a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="foldedlabel" colspan="6"><a>Accessories</a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><a>Accessories</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You can iterate over the `tr`s and check if it has child with specific class and if not then add class to it.

```
$('tr').each(function(){
  if($(this).children('.childClass').length ==0)
    $(this).addClass('parentClass');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `has()` and `not()` selectors

```js
$('tr').not(':has(td[class])').addClass('no');
```

```css
tr.no {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="unfoldedlabel" colspan="6"><a>Accessories</a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="foldedlabel" colspan="6"><a>Accessories</a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><a>Accessories</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```